# Not allowing calls to solr outside localhost

Tags: solr, jetty

I want to not allowing calls to solr which are not coming from localhost.I am using jetty.

Thanks,
Shashwat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how you config Jetty to just use localhost

```
<Call name="addConnector"> 
    <Set name="Host">127.0.0.1</Set> 
    ....
</Call>
```

Answer (score 0):

For solr-5.2.1 I did

```
edit /solr/solr.in.sh
add SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Djetty.host=localhost"
```

from http://foswiki.org/Extensions/SolrPlugin#Installation successfully.